# If $AB=I$ implies $BA=I$ for square matrices over a field K, why do we define inverse matrix in such way?

Tags: matrices, inverse

Let $A$ be a square matrix over a field $K$ and $I$ the identity matrix. The inverse matrix of $A$ (when it exists) is a square matrix $B$ such that $\begin{equation}AB=I=BA\end{equation}$.
It can proved that $AB=I$ implies $BA=I$ for square matrices over a field, so why don't why just define inverse with one of those conditions instead of both (either $AB=I$ or $BA=I$)? I mean like:
A square matrix $A$ over a field $K$ is said to be invertible if there exists a square matrix $B$ such that $AB=I$.

Comment: Because it generalizes to the non-square case?

Comment: I've seen this definition with both conditions even though it specified it was the inverse of a square matrix.

Comment: This explanation doesn't really have content, but maybe it gives some perspective. We abbreviate "there exists $B$ such that $AB=I$" as "$A$ has a right inverse" and we abbreviate "there exists $B$ such that $BA=I$" as "$A$ has a left inverse". We say an inverse is a left and right inverse. In this definition framework, it is a theorem that if $A$ is square and has a left inverse then that left inverse is a right inverse, and vice versa. We don't need to bake that into the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned Ian's answer in the comments to a community wiki answer.

We abbreviate "there exists $B$ such that $AB =I$" as "$A$ has a right inverse" and we abbreviate "there exists $B$ such that $BA =I$" as "$A$ has a left inverse". We say an inverse is a left and right inverse. In this definition framework, it is a theorem that if $A$ is square and has a left inverse then that left inverse is a right inverse, and vice versa. We don't need to bake that into the definition. In general, you don't want your definitions to rely on theorems.

Comment: +1 In general, you don't want your definitions to rely on theorems.

Comment: Also the original definition is generalized to a lot of different entities. If one uses theorems as definitions (which I agree, one shouldnt), than probable det(A)=1 would be the best for invertibility, since it doesnt require to show any existance if you want to proof your matrix in invertible.